# Erlang : Invariable Variables assign pattern in Case Expression or Argument list

Tags: performance, erlang

For the following case:

```
case SomeTuple of
    {} ->
        doing1();
    {A,B,C,D,E,F} ->
        doing2_1(A),
        doing2_2({A,B,C,D,E,F});
    _ ->
        doing3()
end.
```

I prefer to write something like this:

```
case SomeTuple of
    {} ->
        doing1();
    X = {A,_,_,_,_,_} ->
        doing2_1(A),
        doing2_2(X);
    _ ->
        doing3()
end.
```

Questions:

1. Does the second case consume extra memory or other resources?
2. Which approach is recommended?

Comment: first case is illegal. Second case will issue a warning: A is unused, and the clause {} is useless if you really call the same function as in the default one.

Comment: @Pascal I've update the problem, did you get some idea???

Comment: I prefer the second one because it focuses on "interesting" assignments.

Comment: @Steve, Why did you remove the edited text? Anyway, my previous comment is now useless since the second case is the only one which is correct. (with my last correction :o)

Comment: I cleaned up the text because there seemed to be a duplicated restatement of the problem, and it didn't provide any additional questions or possibilities for additional insights. I felt the edits and updates added confusion rather than helping future readers understand the issues and their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version is the only legal one, and a pretty normal way to phrase things. Even more normal is to avoid the case statement entirely (if possible) and do this sort of thing in a function head, even if that means breaking these lines out into a tiny helper function (which gives you a chance to meaningfully *name* the procedure the case match represents and improve the semantics of your code).

There is almost never a case where you should have a "nuple" like `{}`. I can't think of any reason off the top of my head why this should ever occur -- there may be some weirdness with non-Erlang libraries where the semantic purpose of a tuple isn't recognized. (If I got that I would consider it bad data and let it crash on purpose.)

As for performance...

Variables bind as late as possible in Erlang, and actually "binding" is a more lightweight  operation than you might be expecting from other dynamically typed languages that are not functional (even the idea is flexible, since sometimes nothing more than a reference is passed on). The only time you ever wind up wasting cycles doing binding is when you spin out a large number of meaningless intermediate variables that you will never use -- this is why the compiler gives a warning about unused variables.

Here is a case where you are *not* getting meaningless intermediates, though:

```
foo(Data) ->
    {ok, Value} = somefun(Data),
    otherfun(Value).
```

The `{ok, Value}` bit is often regarded by newcomers as a "wasted" assignment because it can't be passed straight through in long function composition. What they are missing is that this is a value *assertion*, not just an assignment. Many functions that are either side-effecty or have a potential to search for and not find something return such an assertion-friendly tuple (reading from an external resource, key-value lookups, etc. for example). These are profoundly important and let you crash your process early on before you start doing insane things with bad data (which is a genuine waste of cycles!).

In any case, this is the *wrong* place to be worrying about performance. Tuple matching is very fast in Erlang, and records are reduced to tuples at compile time, so they are exactly equivalent. Merely passing an argument to a function doesn't require message passing or copying.

Forget about performance until you have a working system to measure. Hypothesizing about performance in a massively concurrent system is about as meaningful as trying to guess how many waves of a certain size a storm is going to produce -- you simply won't know until you have a chance to measure. Everthing in Erlang is traceable, so it is *always* smart to leave performance tweaks for later. Erlang is so friendly to post-development tracing, profiling and tuning that it makes your time far more important than the processor's. Use your time wisely by writing a pretty codebase first, then test it with whatever load you expect. I've had very few cases where I've written idiomatic Erlang code (that is, not putting too much responsibility in one god process) and actually wound up with performance bottlenecks that were not the network, disk access, or some other external resource.

Comment: thanks, I've heard "Let it crash", for this question, all the code just for example, I even never compile it, my mistake. The reason why create this question is because I must follow the project's code style, someone told me to standardize first one that diff my idea. So I wonder if the secondary case get something bad relative to first case.

Answer (score 0):

@haoxian, The only option is the second case. `doing2_2({A,_,_,_,_,_})` is forbidden, this code won't compile. In erlang, the *variable* `_` is not assigned, it just says to the compiler that it should match to any erlang term. `{A,_,_,_,_,_} = T` simply verifies that `T` is a tuple of 6 elements and assigns its first element to `A`.

It is different than using the syntax `_Var`. In this case `_Var` is a true variable that could be used (even if not recommended). This notation indicates to the compiler to do not issue a warning if this variable is not used later in the function. This notation is often used in function, receive or case clauses to remind the signification of unused term:

```
receive
   {test, _From, Msg} -> io:format("receive test message ~p~n",[Msg]);
   {read, From} -> From ! afunction()
end,
```

I also saw this notation in some pattern matching like `{A,_T,_T} = function()` which verifies that the function returns a 3 elements tuple, where second and third elements are equal, and assign the first element to `A`. Note that in this case the usage of `T` instead of `_T` would not cause a warning, but it is clearer for the reader that `_T` will not be used later.

**[edit]**

There are a lot of optimization done by the compiler and the team who developed the beam machine took care of time and memory saving so you should not think about performance and optimization first.

The most important when you write an application is to split it in the right processes with the right responsibilities.

It is also important - in my opinion - to stick to the OTP principles: this will allow you to use many useful tools to debug, trace, tweak ... your application. It will be also easier for other people to understand it.

And of course, like in any language, write your code to make it the most readable by others.

If you ever come to the point where the difference between the 2 code variants matter, I guess that it means that you are in real trouble with your application or that you are trying to solve a problem with the wrong tool.

Comment: thanks @Pascal, `X = {A,_,_,_,_,_}` in case expression is for matching the 6 element tuple, the `X` is for the `doing2_2(X)`, so I would not write a long chain like `{A,B,C,D,E,F}`, it seem more tidy if `X` will be used in many places, but if I do that, would it consume extra resource???